# Escaping parameters passed to perl script within Windows Shell

Tags: asp.net, perl, escaping, windows-shell

I have a perl script that was provided by a vendor, and that takes a series of parameters. I would like to call this via a Windows Shell object in ASP classic.

If I type the following in the cmd line on the web server, it works just fine:

```
path_to_perl\perl.exe path_to_pl\myfile.pl --arg1 "something" --arg2 "somethingelse"
```

If I do the following in ASP classic, it doesn't work:

```
strCMD = "path_to_perl\perl.exe path_to_pl\myfile.pl --arg1 ""something"" --arg2  ""somethingelse"""
Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("cmd.exe /c " & strCMD)
```

The issue is that the argument have all sorts of special characters, so I need to quote them. I have read conflicting information as to how I should escape them - via a caret or a back-slash. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `cmd.exe /c`?

Comment: That's how I've been running perl scripts before. Note that if the strCMD doesn't have any arguments, the code works just fine.

Comment: Furthermore, the special characters in ""something"" and ""something else"" are all over the place - $, /, \, @, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Shoulf call Perl directly, like this:

```
system_call_test( 'c:/complete/path_to_pl/myfile.pl --arg1 "something" ... ' )
```

See the discussion here: **[How to call perl programs from ASP page](http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-to-call-perl-126458.html)** 
and aspecially the answers of *Charles K. Clarkson* here.

It will simplify the problem, as you will not have to deal with escaping characters 
for ASP, CMD and Perl - all at the same time.

(in that discussion the problem was a syntax-error at the Perl-script, eventually,
but it still shows how to code it in ASP).